# Can you set/slot CSS variables of a HTML content template with JavaScript? If so how?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not use any frameworks and try to create an HTML content template with `<template` and `slot`s for using it in slightly modified ways in my main document. I could use JavaScript string templates and add it to the `document` but would prefer to have the HTML not pollute my script file.
The setup is like this:

Definition:

`template.html`

```html
<template id="my-template">
  <style>
    /*** static style attributes ***/
    .myTemplate {
      position: relative;
      
      --radius: 30px;  /* I gladly take <slot> here if possible */
    }
    .myTemplate > .drawing {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .myTemplate > .text {
      font-size: 1em;

      position: absolute;
      top: 50%; left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .myTemplate circle {
      /* e.g. stroke width should be related to the radius, ignore setting the radius */
      stroke-width: calc(.5 * var(--radius));
      /* imagine several more depending attributes */
    }
  </style>
  
  <div class="myTemplate">
    <div class="drawing">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"
         />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><slot name="text">foo</slot></div><!-- this slot wobks as expected -->
  </div>
</template>
```

and

`style.css`

```css
/* free to modify style attributes */
.myTemplate {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 100px;

  background: yellow;
}
.myTemplate circle {
  fill: #fff0;
  stroke: #e28;
}
```

Expected usage:

`script.js`

```
const templateContent = document.getElementById('my-template').content;

let clone1 = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
clone1.querySelector('slot[name=text]').textContent = 'bar';
document.body.appendChild(clone1);

let clone2 = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
clone2.querySelector('slot[name=text]').textContent = 'baz';
// clone2.querySelector('slot[name=radius]').textContent = 22; /* no luck here */
// clone2.style.setProperty('--radius', '22');  /* does not work as well*/
document.body.appendChild(clone2);
```

So, there are several attributes which base on the same value (here: `--radius`) and of course I would like to just set this one value instead of half a dozen others.

I neither could make this work using `slot`s nor accessing `style.`methods of the template's instance. One crucial aspect is that individual clones must be parametrized differently.

What am I doing wrong? What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are forgetting that `.content` on a `template` is returning a `DocumentFragment` and not a proper HTML element.

So the following won't work since a `DocumentFragment` doesn't have a style attribute:

```js
clone2.style.setProperty("--radius", '22px');
```

But this will work:

```js
clone2.querySelector(".myTemplate").style.setProperty("--radius", '22px');
```

*P.S.*
If you just did something like `.firstElementChild`, you would find the style tag inside the template, rather than the div you want.

```js
const templateContent = document.getElementById('my-template').content;

let clone1 = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
clone1.querySelector('slot[name=text]').textContent = 'bar';
document.body.appendChild(clone1);

let clone2 = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
clone2.querySelector('slot[name=text]').textContent = 'baz';
clone2.querySelector(".myTemplate").style.setProperty("--radius", '22px');
document.body.appendChild(clone2);
```

```css
.myTemplate {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 100px;

  background: yellow;
}
.myTemplate circle {
  fill: #fff0;
  stroke: #e28;
}
```

```html
<template id="my-template">
  <style>
    /*** static style attributes ***/
    .myTemplate {
      position: relative;
      
      --radius: 30px;  /* I gladly take <slot> here if possible */
    }
    .myTemplate > .drawing {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .myTemplate > .text {
      font-size: 1em;

      position: absolute;
      top: 50%; left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .myTemplate circle {
      /* e.g. stroke width should be related to the radius, ignore setting the radius */
      stroke-width: calc(.5 * var(--radius));
      /* imagine several more depending attributes */
    }
  </style>
  
  <div class="myTemplate">
    <div class="drawing">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"
         />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><slot name="text">foo</slot></div><!-- this slot wobks as expected -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Leveraging the `CSSStyleDeclaration: setProperty() method` solves the problem and one could easily write a function to parameterise the properties being set.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware that this is the best answer so far (What happened to the other one?? `ô.Ô`). Unfortunatelly it does not work. `...style` returns an empty `CSSStyleDeclaration`, i.e. the default (`--radius: 30px`) is not there. Also if I apply the proposal the result has not the expected width. It's only a thin line, likely the default value for `circle`'s `stroke-width`. So I am still fiddling around.

Comment: Style is the inline style so it starts empty and when you populate it it overrides the current value. Obviously if want a larger value then set that. I've added the code to show the effect.

Comment: The only other cross-browser API for interacting with styles is [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), but as the docs say, this is for reading styles and not for writing them and it points you towards using `.style` instead.

Comment: Many thanks for putting together the example. The mistake I did when I applied your suggestion on my own was missing out the unit for the stroke width! That was the sole reason it did not work for me...